# can't set resultCode for startActivityForResult in the abnormal situation

Tags: android

my program flow in my normal situation is

```
activity A (start"activity B"using startActivityForResult)
activity B (setResult and finish(), return to "activity A")
activity A (onActivityResult having result)
```

in the abnormal situation, activity B can call another activity,C.
flow is like this

```
activity A (start"activity B"using startActivityForResult)
activity B (start"activity C")
activity C (finish(),return to activity B)
activity B (setResult and finish(), return to "activity A")
activity A (onActivityResult having **no result!**)
```

at this after case,how to send "activity B result" to activity A?

Answer (score 1):

If, by writing `(start"activity C")` you mean that B does not use `startActivityForResult()` to start C, then B would simply have to do just that, such that it can wait for `C` to return until it delivers its result back to `A`.